# how to control fast report objects from a form

Tags: delphi

how i could control objects in fast report like text width or label caption
from delphi form befor showing report 
i have delphi xe2 fast report 4 and it's my first experince in fast report

```
in report builder i can do this but now i cant't

dynamc report is vey important it's change all time depending on varibels came   
from delphi form
```

becasue i have dynamic report and it's all time change depend on text from the form

```
dynamc report is vey important it's change all time depending on varibels came   
from delphi form
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a FastReport object's components, one option would be to use the object's `FindComponent` method, which returns the component by the specified name (or `nil`, if not found):

```
varname := YourFastReportObject.FindComponent('ComponentName');
```

Casting the result to an appropriate type, you could then access the component's methods and properties, like in this example:

```
var
  varname: TfrxMemoView;

...

varname := TfrxMemoView(YourFastReportObject.FindComponent('ComponentName'));
if varname <> nil then
  varname.Width := varname.Width * 1.2;
```